# Find the z-transform

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

I have these expressions for which I need the z-transformed functions. Please help.
[The Question Expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HpW4.jpg)

[My attempt for the first question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmcKB.jpg)

[My attempt for the second question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwMfL.jpg)

[My attempt for the third question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6QbW.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Math formatting tips are [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Please transcribe equations instead of linking to images, thanks.  Also, when writing a question, be sure to show what work you have already done and all the relevant information, so people don't talk over your head or explain things you already know.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I actually did try the first three questions, although I'm unsure as to whether it's right. Hence, I didn't put it here. The last three problems, I have no idea.

Comment: @Ak. Would you help me now?

Comment: Please put your first results in your question. Besides, it is essential to have a double **table** of Z-transforms (a table of classical correspondences, and a table giving the main properties of Z-transfom). Do you have such a table ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I looked this table up on the internet and was able to get through 3 of the problems. I have no idea about the last three problems. I just need SOMEONE to tell me HOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP has included their efforts, I'm posting this answer.
For $|z|>|r|$,
$$\mathcal Z \{r^n\cos(\omega_0n)u(n)\}=\frac{1-rz^{-1}\cos\omega_0}{1-2rz^{-1}\cos\omega_0+r^2z^{-2}}$$

and

$$\mathcal Z \{r^n\sin(\omega_0n)u(n)\}=\frac{rz^{-1}\sin\omega_0}{1-2rz^{-1}\cos\omega_0+r^2z^{-2}}$$

So for the question d, let $r = (ae^{-b})$

For the question e, $$x(n) = (n-1)a^{n-2} = a^{-2}(na^n-a^n)\\
\Rightarrow \mathcal Z \{x(n)\} = a^{-2}\left[-z\frac d{dz}\left(\frac{z}{z-a}\right)-\frac{z}{z-a}\right]=\frac{z(2a-z)}{a^2(a-z)^2}$$

For $f$, first simplify it.

$$\begin{align}x(n) &= (n-3)\left(\frac14\right)^{n-2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}2 - \frac\pi2\right)u(n) = 16(n-3)\left(\frac14\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)u(n)\\& = 16\left[n\left(\frac14\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)u(n)-3\left(\frac14\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)u(n)\right]\end{align} $$

Now, for $\omega_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$$\mathcal Z \left\{\left(\frac14\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)\right\}=\frac{\frac{z^{-1}}{4}\cdot1}{1-2\cdot 0 + \frac{z^{-2}}{16}}=\frac{4z^{-1}}{16+z^{-2}}$$

Then use, $\mathcal Z \{nx(n)\} = -z\frac{d}{dz}X(z)$

---

Your answers for a and b are correct. The answer of c is incorrect.

$$\begin{align}\mathcal Z \left\{2^nu(-n)+\left(\frac14\right)^nu(n-2)\right\}&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty2^nu(-n)z^{-n} + \left(\frac14\right)^2\mathcal Z\left\{\left(\frac14\right)^{n-2}u(n-2)\right\}\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty2^nu(-n)z^{-n} + \left(\frac14\right)^2z^{-2}\mathcal Z\left\{\left(\frac14\right)^{n}u(n)\right\}\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^02^nz^{-n} + \frac1{16}z^{-2}\frac{z}{z-\frac14} \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac z2\right)^n+\frac{1}{4z(4z-1)} \\
&=\frac{1}{1-\frac z2}+\frac{1}{4z(4z-1)} \\
&= \frac{2}{2-z}+\frac{1}{4z(4z-1)} \end{align}$$

and ROC : $\frac14 < |z| <2$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd also appreciate it if you could tell me if my attempts for the first three questions are correct.

Comment: @revmatcher I've added something, kindly check

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!